# nagios-herald Install and config

Tags: monitoring, nagios

I tried to install nagios-herald on my test VM.
I tried to configure herald to send emails. When I tried to send mail via command, It's working but not able to fetch/send with the proper formatted.

Below are commands for your reference.

```
[root@localhost ~]# /usr/local/nagios-herald/bin/nagios-herald --env-file /usr/local/nagios-herald/test/env_files/nagios_vars.EXAMPLE --formatter=check_ping -r amit@example.com -y nagios@example.com --message-type email -u http://192.168.124.25 --trace
```

Please anyone suggest me for configuration of nagios-herald with Nagios.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip, dont forget to set the following in `nagios.cfg`:

```
enable_environment_macros=1
```

Also, here is mine `commands.cfg`:

```
define command {
    command_name    notify-host-by-email
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios-herald/bin/nagios-herald --message-type email -r $CONTACTEMAIL$ --formatter=$_HOSTMESSAGE_FORMATTER_NAME$ --nagios-cgi-url=http://192.168.0.1/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi --reply-to=nagios@somehost
}

define command {
    command_name    notify-service-by-email
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios-herald/bin/nagios-herald --message-type email -r $CONTACTEMAIL$ --formatter=$_SERVICEMESSAGE_FORMATTER_NAME$ --nagios-cgi-url=http://192.168.0.1/nagios/cgi-bin/cmd.cgi --reply-to=nagios@somehost
}
```

After this you should have it working.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `check_ping` formatter in the default project. If you've written one and it lives outside of the project directory, you can teach `nagios-herald` how to find it with `-F </path/to/custom/formatters>`.

I also noticed you are using the `--trace` option. If you specify either `-l <logfile>` in the command or `logfile:` in the config, you'll see what issues `nagios-herald` is encountering. I'm betting you'll see it state that it can't locate the `check_ping` formatter and fell back to the base formatter.